# Change target directory for a specific profile in the pom file

Tags: maven, pom.xml

In the pom file, we can override `project.build.directory` for a specific profile

```
<profile>
  <id>foo</id>
  <build>
    <directory>${project.basedir}/foo_directory/target</directory>
  </build>
</profile>
```

My question is, what happens to other directories depending on `project.build.directory`?

for example these two:

```
<outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
<testOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
```

If I run maven with `foo` profile and I use `outputDirectory` or `testOutputDirectory` will maven take into consideration the new target directory?

Comment: First question: Why do you like to do that ? What is the reason for doing this? What kind of problem do you have?

Comment: @khmarbaise I have a use case where two target directories are needed (foo1/target and foo2/target) instead of the default one.

Comment: That does not answer the question of why? As I asked: Why do you need that? What is the purpose and what kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: The use case is very specific to the project I'm working on. I'm writing an integration test and I need to have two instances of the application (target folder) running in the same time. The environment is set using the pom file.

Comment: So you build for each environment ? Sounds completely wrong. Build once and start twice .. in an integration test you could use ProcessBuilder to start two instances very easy...We are using that to run our e2e tests (combined that with testcontainers etc.) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this should work.

You can verify this by running `mvn help:effective-pom` and `mvn help:effective-pom -P foo` to compare the effective-pom with the default profile and the `foo` profile.

You can then verify that the configuration property `${project.build.directory}` is replaced by the correct value.

As a test i have configured the following in `pom.xml`:

```
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>foo</id>
            <build>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/foo_directory/target</directory>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

And the default effective pom becomes:

```
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>D:\TestProject\src\main\java</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>D:\TestProject\src\test\java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>D:\TestProject\target\classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>D:\TestProject\target\test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
```

And the `foo` effective pom becomes:

```
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>D:\TestProject\src\main\java</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>D:\TestProject\src\test\java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>D:\TestProject\foo_directory\target\classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>D:\TestProject\foo_directory\target\test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
```